# Buoyancy on the Moon

Tags: newtonian-gravity, buoyancy, moon

A body is floating partly immersed in a liquid. The body and the liquid are taken to the Moon. What will happen next? Will its immersed part come out of the liquid? Will it sink? Will it continue to float as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual simple argument based on Archimedes' principle, the volume of fluid displaced is simply $V_{\rm disp}=m/\rho_{\rm f}$ where $m$ is the mass of the object and $\rho_{\rm f}$ is the density of the fluid in which it is floating. The mass of the object obviously doesn't change by moving it to the Moon (though its *weight* does). Provided the density of the fluid doesn't change when transported to the Moon (probably reasonable for a liquid, ignoring the fact that it will likely boil in the vacuum), then the volume displaced is unchanged and you won't notice any difference. This is a somewhat long-winded statement of the fact that the buoyant force is independent of the local gravitational acceleration (in a simple treatment where the fluid properties are *also* independent of $g$, which isn't always the case).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the volume of ball immersed in water on the moon will be greater than that on earth. It's because, when you say it is partly immersed, buoyancy due to air must also be considered and there is no air on moon. So, the buoyant force experienced by the body on moon will be less, making it get a bit more submerged.
(Sorry for my english though, it's not that good but understandable I guess)

Comment: Without air, we generally get no liquid also (the liqud will evaporate in vacuum).

Comment: You are absolutely right about that. But I think, the affect of reduced pressure on the volume of liquid is neglected in most of these questions, because the volume is supposed to be constant. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion.